# How to loop to insert the records to a table by taking the data from two (2) other tables?

Tags: c#, sql, loops

I have 3 tables: tblDepartment, tblFunction, tblDepartmentFunction as below.
tblDepartment having one to many with tblDepartmentFunction 
tblFunction having one to many with tblDepartmentFunction 
I need code C# to run a loop to insert the records to tblDepartmentFunction by taking DepartmentID (1) record from tblDepartment together taking FunctionID (1,2,3,4,5,6) of all records from tblFunction please refer the below drawing:

[image: Table drawing]

Please help me to obtain the above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can feed an insert command with a query, and that query can join two or more tables. So you don't need to code a loop in C#, you can just insert those rows executing a single SQL statement.

Concretely :

```
insert into tblDepartmentFuncion (DepartmentId, FunctionId)
            select DepartmentId, FunctionId
            from tblDepartment, tblFunction
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please note that table function may have many record, the amount of its records only identify by count command, not only 6. So I think loop while or for should be applied to insert the record.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you, now I have modified it so it will insert all the existing Department functions, not only 6. It's much easier for you to do these inserts on a single very simple SQL statement than coding a loop in C#.

Comment: The downvoter could explain what does he doesn't like with this very simple, well explained and perfectly functional solution ?.